# Word Mail Merge with Excel data has to be saved in files with custom names based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a letter written in Word and a worksheet full of data in Excel.
I need to do a Mail Merge in Word that uses the worksheet's data.

The problem is every Mail Merge has to be saved as a different Word file and, also, every file has to be saved with a name from the data used in the Mail Merge.

For example:
My Excel has a table with 3 columns called Name, Surname, Birthday. This table has 10 rows.
I need to do the Mail Merge in Word with Name, Surname and Birthday.
Every Mail Merge has to be saved in a different file (in the end, we'll have 10 files, 1 for each row).
Every file has to be named as the relative Surname extracted from the Mail Merge.

I found this VBA code online and tried it in Word:

```vb
' Modulo1 - Modulo'

Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

On Error GoTo ErrH

Dim mm As Word.MailMerge
Dim i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set mm = ThisDocument.MailMerge
With mm
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    With .DataSource
        For i = 1 To .RecordCount
            .FirstRecord = i
            .LastRecord = i
            mm.Execute
            With Application.ActiveDocument
                .SaveAs "C:\Users\Alessandro\Desktop\excel udine\TRIESTE\" & Format(i, "0000") _
                  , wdFormatDocument _
                  , AddToRecentFiles:=False
                .Saved = True
                .Close
            End With
        Next
    End With
End With

ExitProc:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set mm = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrH:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitProc

End Sub
```

This code saves every Mail Merge. The problem is that the filename is a number like 0001, 0002, etc.
I need to set that name to a value I store in the Excel Worksheet and also use in the Mail Merge.

Comment: If used in mail merge, you should be able to get the the field value via `mm.DataSource.DataFields("FieldName").Value`.

Comment: @KostasK. I tried it, but the expression keeps giving me the values from the first row and that's it. I tried to access this value in a debug session, but no, still gives out the values in the first row.

Comment: Try to store the value in a variable before calling `mm.Execute`.

Comment: @KostasK. I tried that to, it just saves the first row result like before. I can't figure out why it keeps giving just that one, the Mail Merge works perfectly and prints the right values, but I don't know why I can't access that data in VBA.

Comment: See *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips & Tricks** page at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my own problem. I still don't know why I couldn't make work the old code, but this code works perfectly:

```
Public Sub Mail_Merge()

On Error GoTo ErrH

Dim mm As Word.MailMerge
Dim singleDoc As Document
Dim i
Dim nameFile As String
Dim path As String

path = "WRITE PATH TO SAVE FILE"
nameFile = "WRITE COLUMN NAME FROM MAIL MERGE"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set mm = ThisDocument.MailMerge

mm.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord

For i = 1 To mm.DataSource.RecordCount
    mm.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument

    mm.DataSource.FirstRecord = mm.DataSource.ActiveRecord
    mm.DataSource.LastRecord = mm.DataSource.ActiveRecord
    
    mm.Execute False

    Set singleDoc = ActiveDocument

    singleDoc.SaveAs2 _
        FileName:=path & mm.DataSource.DataFields(nameFile).Value, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False

    singleDoc.Close False

    mm.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
Next

ExitProc:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set mm = Nothing
    Exit Sub
   
ErrH:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitProc
   
End Sub
```